# Custom Branch.io events not showing up in Dashboard using iOS (Objective-C) SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, branch.io, custom-events

I have a custom event I'm attempting to track that shows when the user reaches a certain page in my iOS app.

In this app, I have filled in the proper `branch_app_domain` and `branch_key`my branch live key and `.link` domain

I have also enabled Associated Domains in the project with the same `.link` domain as well as its alternate

The app is not in the App Store yet, nor is it in TestFlight.

I can confirm that clicking the .link tracks clicks successfully, and shows at least one install.

I use the following code to track it:

```
BranchEvent *event = [BranchEvent customEventWithName:@"email_view"];
event.customData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:signupDict];
[event logEvent];
```

The event seems to complete without error

The same behavior is exhibited when tracking standard events, like

```
BranchEvent * event2 = [BranchEvent standardEvent:BranchStandardEventSearch];
[event2 logEvent];
```

That is, it doesn't long the above either in Branch

However, DeepLinks generated within the app do log in Branch.

Why dont my events show on Branch.io's dashboard? There is no reference to this event anywhere. Not in the live view, Source view, or Content view

Answer (score 0):

The Branch dashboard does show analytics for attributed events on the [Sources](https://branch.dashboard.branch.io/sources) page. If your custom event is attributed to a Branch link, you should be able to view this data by enabling the custom event column on the top right corner.

If you are tracking organic events, this data should be available as a part of [CSV Exports](https://branch.dashboard.branch.io/data-import-export/csv-exports).

You should also be able to view a stream of events on the [Liveview](https://branch.dashboard.branch.io/liveview/events) by switching to the custom event tab. Data on the Liveview is not persisted and is helpful for development purposes.

You can write to ***integrations@branch.io*** if you have more questions.